# How to unwrap arbitrarily deeply nested optionals in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift4

As an exercise in Swift, I am trying to write an extension method that will unwrap arbitrarily deeply nested optionals. *This has little practical use and is simply an exploration of Swift's type system.*

Examples of arbitrarily deeply nested optionals are `Optional<Optional<Optional<Int>>>` and `Optional<Optional<Optional<Optional<Int>>>>`.

The only way I've discovered to do this is to use type erasure:

```
protocol TypeErasedOptional {
    func deeplyUnwrap() -> Any?
}

extension Optional: TypeErasedOptional {
    func deeplyUnwrap() -> Any? {
        switch self {
        case .none: return nil
        case .some(let wrapped as TypeErasedOptional): return wrapped.deeplyUnwrap()
        case .some(let wrapped): return wrapped
        }
    }

    func unwrap<T>(_ type: T.Type = T.self) -> T? {
       switch deeplyUnwrap() {
       case .none: return nil
       case .some(let wrapped as T): return wrapped
       default: return nil
       }
    }
}
```

This works well. We can unwrap a deeply nested optional, but unfortunately we have to restate the `Wrapped` type:

```
let x = Optional<Optional<Optional<Int>>>(3)
let y = x.unwrap(Int.self)
```

I can't think of any way to do this without type erasure. And once you use type erasure, you must restate the type to get it back. I don't want this. Can someone more versed in Swift let me know either that this cannot be done or whether there is another way?

Comment: Swift's casting machinery can drill through arbitrary levels of optionality, so you could just say `let y = x as? Int` :)

Comment: @Hamish I'm well aware! But that wouldn't be as fun.

Comment: Fair enough – I'm pretty sure you won't be able to achieve this without re-stating the `Wrapped` type in some way, as you can't recursively unfold a generic placeholder (i.e you cannot express "if the `Wrapped` type is `Optional`, recursively consider its `Wrapped` type").

Comment: For fun, you could create your own wrapper type to keep track of the original wrapped value (https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/e08e97f3170f8f30f8ca9df21a6ec365), but that's probably not what you had in mind ;)

Comment: @Hamish "you can't recursively unfold a generic placeholder". Right. This is why I had to resort to type erasure. However, I was hoping there was some clever workaround. :)

Comment: This is much more useful in Swift 4.1+, where the compiler no longer automatically fully unwraps nested optionals.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that provides flattening up to a six-levels `Optional`:

```
extension Optional {
    func flatten() -> Wrapped? {
        return self
    }

    func flatten<T>() -> T? where Wrapped == T? {
        return map { $0.flatten() } ?? nil
    }

    func flatten<T>() -> T? where Wrapped == T?? {
        return map { $0.flatten() } ?? nil
    }

    func flatten<T>() -> T? where Wrapped == T??? {
        return map { $0.flatten() } ?? nil
    }

    func flatten<T>() -> T? where Wrapped == T???? {
        return map { $0.flatten() } ?? nil
    }

    func flatten<T>() -> T? where Wrapped == T????? {
        return map { $0.flatten() } ?? nil
    }
}
```

The advantage of the above solution is the fact that is type safe, the disadvantages are the fact that it's statically typed (e.g. can't call `flatten()` on `Any` variables), and that you need to add more and more overloads if you need to support more and more nesting levels.

Comment: That seems very inefficient. There should be a single and universal method.

Comment: @George_E I mentioned about that in the end of the answer. If you have a better solution, please feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score -1):

`Optional.flatMap(_:)` seems to do the trick. E.g.:

```
var a: String??? = "aaa"
let b: String = a?.flatMap{$0} ?? "<nil>"

print(b) // "aaa"
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) doesn't clearly mention this functionality, but it works.

**edit:** It's not, see the comment below.

Comment: The mix of `?.` and `flatMap` and `??` are working together to remove exactly three layers here. It's not recursive. Try setting `a` to `String????` instead and it'll stop working.

Comment: That's a bummer.